# Training padding on a predictive model

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, data-science

Currently I have a model trying to predict how long it takes for a couple of restaurants to make my order.  After training it, I have a model which has roughly 60% values which are under the actual value, and 40% which are over.  I wanted to train another model on top of this as a "padding" model so that if I add the results of the padding model to this model, I can get around 90% early.

What is the best way to go about creating this padding model?  I want to optimize it such that there is the least amount of padding possible, yet maintain a constraint of 90% of the end result are early (predicted value is > actual value)

Thanks!

Comment: Is the distribution between your training set and your test set the same ?

Comment: yeah they are the same

Comment: @Andy how about training a "residual" model that learns the difference?